# how to generate all the numbers in the range? in python

Tags: python, random

how do I generate all the numbers in the given range without repeat
this is the code that i wrote:-

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(55340232221128655000,73786976201083584000)
hex_number =format(random_number,'x')
hex_number = ''+hex_number
fullurl = '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'+str(hex_number)
print(fullurl)
```

how to generate all the numbers between 55340232221128655000 and 73786976201083584000 without any repeat

Comment: Why are you using `random`? Just use `for number in range(55340232221128655000,73786976201083584001)`

Comment: But what are you going to do with so many numbers? If you can process a million of them every second, it will take almost 600,000 years to do all of them.

Comment: With a range that ridiculously large, you can't.  The only way to avoid duplicates is to keep a list of what's been used (or unused), and you would need 80 petabytes of memory to keep that list.

Comment: if i use ``` for number in range(55340232221128655000,73786976201083584001)``` will it generate all the numbers in the given range without repete?

Comment: Yes, it will generate all of them in order.

Comment: oh my i am trying to solve the bitcoin puzzle from 2015 so im trying to randomize the range the author has given so im brutforcing every randomly generated number

Comment: You'll need to come up with a more efficient method, there are too many possibilities to brute-force it.

Comment: Sounds like the thing to do is not worry about repeats. Given the fraction of the space you're likely to search in any reasonably time, repeats simply aren't likely enough to matter.

Comment: any effective pointers that you have in your mind..?

Comment: okey sooo the range the author has given is 20000000000000000 : 3ffffffffffffffff (36893488147419103232 : 73786976294838206463) what would be the best strategy to figure this..??

Comment: THERE IS NO STRATEGY.  Unless you are a cryptography expert, there is NO POINT in attempting the Bitcoin puzzle.  It will simply waste your time.  Find something that is achievable.

Comment: @TimRoberts a 12 year old solved a puzzle with a bigger key space i think its not about the how much knowledge one holds its about the technique one applies right..??

Comment: You have to understand the key space in order to reduce the problem from the current 25 quintillion possibilities.    Brute force simply will not do it.

Comment: @TimRoberts what is the best way to speed up the process the process..?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get all numbers

```
for num in range(55340232221128655000,73786976201083584000):
    print(num)
```

or you can do it by this method

```
for i in range(the no of numbers you want):
    random_number = random.randint(55340232221128655000,73786976201083584000)
    list1=[]
    if random_number not in list1:
        list1.append(random_number)
        print(random_number)
```

Comment: better use a set, they are made for checking if sth is in them way more efficiently than lists and they don't allow duplicates automatically, also don't create it every iteration (for sets you don't even need the `if random_number not in list1`, it just won't add it there)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of getting all the numbers from the range to a list or you can take the `.tolist()` part off.

```
import numpy as np

list = np.arange(55340232221128655000,73786976201083584001).tolist()
print(list)
```

here it prints the list too.

Comment: That list requires 80 petabytes of memory to construct.